# Event listener on appended input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a keyup event listener on classes called userInput, but after appending multiple input boxes with the same class, this event listener will not fire from the new input boxes.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="userInput">
    <button type="button" id="add_input">Add</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".userInput").on("keyup", function(){
        alert("Key has been released");
    });   

    var target = $("#wrapper"),
        innerHTML = "<div><input type=\"text\" class=\"userInput\"></div><br>";
    $("#add_input").on("click", function(){
        target.append(innerHTML);
    });
});
```

The event listener fires for the original input box, but doesn't for any of the new appended input boxes which have the same class.

Comment: Sorry it's a dupe, I couldn't really find a similar problem on here but I guess I wasn't looking hard enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(".wrapper").on("keyup", ".userInput", function(){
    alert("Key has been released");
});
```